# Riemann Integral - Partitioning - Nets

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Everybody Hello, I'm confused about the following integral:

Consider the following:
Riemann Integral: $\int f dx:=\{\sum_{E\in\mathcal{E}} f(E)\lambda(E)\}_\mathcal{E}$
Domain: $I:=[0,1]$
Function: $f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$, $f(0):=0$

The Problem is now:
This should be Riemann integrable on the compact unit interval as we know by formal antiderivative and neglecting the boundary, however, comparing upper and lower sum or equivalently tagged partitions it shouldn't be Riemann integrable ...did I miss sth?

That is in Detail:
Take the refining sequence of partitions: $\mathcal{E}_n:=\{(\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]\}_{k=1}^n$
Then compute the upper sum by taking the suprema: $\sum_{k=1}^n\sup f(E_k)\lambda(E_k)=\infty\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{1}}\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{n}\ldots=\infty$
...this already tells us it shouldn't be Riemann integrable

Moreover, It seems as if the function even fails to be integrable as improper integral.
Am I missing sth when simply considering equidistant partitions? Doing so I end up with sum variaty of the Riemann Zeta Function being divergent...

Comment: Put here your calculations for "... comparing upper and lower sum..."

Comment: Since $f$ is not bounded it is *not* Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. The known finite value of the intended integral results from considering it as an *improper integral* resulting from integrals over $[\epsilon,1]$ and passing to the limit $\epsilon\to 0+$.

Comment: Ah right, thx! ...btw, are you THE prof. christian blatter??? small fan of you =D

Comment: It seems as if the function isn't even integrable for $\epsilon>0$. Am I missing sth when simply considering equidistant partitions?

Comment: For $\epsilon > 0$, the function is Riemann-integrable on $[\epsilon,1]$. What problem do you see when trying to prove that?

Comment: @Freeze_S: That's me.

Comment: Ok, for simplicity let: $\epsilon=1/N$ When I use now a partition as $(\frac{k-1}{Nn},\frac{k}{Nn}\rbrack$ ranging from $k=n+1$ up to $k=n N$ I'll end up with the upper sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt {Nn}}\sum_{k=n+1}^{Nn}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$ and a lower sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt {Nn}}\sum_{k=n+1}^{Nn}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ k-1}}$ where I'm not sure wether the corresponding sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt {Nn}}\sum_{k=n}^{Nn}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ occuring in both actually converge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the function is improperly riemann integrable. While considering partitions one has to be careful with taking limit same time